# How to filtering Doctrine ManytoOne relationship table by id?

Tags: php, symfony, angular, doctrine-orm

I have 3 entities:

- First one Seances
- Second lessons
- Last one SeanceLesson entities

I have a form in angular 2. First I will select seance, then select lesson. But this point difficult for me. Because 1 lesson just have a seance. Seance may have more lessons. Shortly when I selected a seance, must list this seance lesson(s). How can do it as simple way?

Comment: did you set many-to-one relation in doctrine ?

Comment: yes, i did relation. @mith

Comment: $lessons =  Lessons::findBy(array(
        'scene_id' => $scene_id
    ));
foreach($lessons as $lesson){
    $lesson->getSeanceLesson()->toArray();
}

Comment: @mith I guess you mean seance_id , but it is not working. How can left join SeanceLesson table and seances table ?

Comment: @mith Lesson table doesn't have seance_id or Seance doesn't have lesson_id . I have pivot table seance_lessons. Any table have a entity. I hope so i can explain my cause

Comment: Can you provide full code of your entities